# Get current image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I get the current image size when I'm using css to scale the image?
I'm trying to get the instantaneous image size has the window is re-sized which changes the size of the image.

I'm thinking it's some kind of `jQuery` `.height()` `.width()`

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mEMNq/)

**The CSS**

```
#full_image{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

#full_image ul li img{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%
}

#full_image .full_close{
 background-color: red;
 top: 10px;     
 cursor: pointer;    
 height: 29px;
 opacity: 1;
 position: absolute;    
 width: 29px;
 z-index: 999;
 right: 10px;
}

#full_image .next_big{
 background-color: red;
  top: 50%;     
  cursor: pointer;    
  height: 29px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;    
  width: 29px;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 0px;
}

#full_image .prev_big{
   background-color: red;
   top: 50%;     
   cursor: pointer;    
   height: 29px;
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;    
   width: 29px;
   z-index: 999;
   left: 0px;
   color: #222;
    }
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id="full_image"> 
  <ul><li><a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a></li> </ul>    
    <a href="#" class="full_close"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button next_big"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button prev_big"></a>           
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.  That's the way i'd go.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        console.log($(this).height()); 
        console.log($(this).width()); 
    })

})
```

updated fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/mEMNq/2

Comment: `console.log($(this).height())` should be `console.log($(this).height());` same with the next line..just simple thing, nothing major. also you had an extra `</div>` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/mEMNq/6/)

Comment: k.  thnx.  the extra div was @wanting-to-learn who asked the question.  I just added the JS ;)

Comment: Thanks that worked now how can I say store the height and use it as a global var?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
(function($) {
    alert($('img').height());
    alert($('img').width());
})(jQuery);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mEMNq/5/)

Also you can try using the [element.clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientWidth?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.clientWidth) and [element.clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientHeight?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.clientHeight)

Comment: Thanks but this only works once. I need it to work continuously

Comment: every time you re-size the window

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done:

```
(function($) {
    alert($('img').height());
    alert($('img').width());
})(jQuery);
```

Just alerting the height and width of the image. You may do the necessary manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using either non-standard IE `element.currentStyle` property or DOM Level 2 standard `getComputedStyle` method.

here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/mEMNq/4/